# Why is “אֱלהִים” (Elohim) spelled like god ha-yam (El the sea), with no “o” sound, in Genesis and Exodus?

Tags: hebrew, genesis

Shouldn't it be spelled אֱל**ו**הִים?
Is there some reason it's not?
I did some googling but could only find pages on other topics.
Apologies if I missed something.

Comment: Step - I suggested a change to the title, but wanted to be sure it is consistent with what you intended.  Did you mean "God Ha-Yam" or really mean "God Ha-Yod"? (Yad could be Hand, Yod is a letter, Yam is sea...".   I can see an argument for "El Ha Yam", especially since diacritics, (vowel pointings), didn't even exist until 900ad.  Also, Paleo-Hebrew could hide spaces between words.

Answer (score 4):

The following is what I came across when having the same question a while back. The subject isn't settled for me yet, but had to move on.

## אֱלֹהִים֮

Lamed has a 'top dot', called a cholam/holam chaser/haser when over letters other than vav. If over a vav, it is called a cholam malei. The top-dot represents a vav.

The hey has a 'bottom dot', which is called a chiriq. The chiriq represents a yod.

The way I found it explained is that the Masoretes chose to 'shorten'/save space in the Tanach by substituting some actual yods and vavs with "puncta extraordinaire" (top and bottom dots, among other dot uses).

So, in the case of 'Elohim', it would actually read "Aluhiim" - which gives me pause on the theory.

However, I did find examples of the Dead Sea Scrolls having "Eluhim":

**Edit** to add source: In the Beginning: A Short History of the Hebrew Language
By Joel Hoffman (p. 137 - Google Books)

[image: DDS Eluhim]

**EDIT:** Just found two interesting resources:

1. Ancient Hebrew Research Center (AHRC) (Jeff Benner) - Shows differences between the Masoretic and DSS - differences I was not aware of before, like Maso. K with qamatz vs DSS KH.

https://www.ancient-hebrew.org/dss/great-isaiah-scroll-and-the-masoretic-text.htm

https://www.ancient-hebrew.org/dss/dead-sea-scroll-text-of-psalm-138.htm

2. The Dead Sea Scrolls Study Edition by FG Martinez - free PDF - pp. 1386

http://superbook.org/AUDIOBOOK/SECRET/The_Dead_Sea_Scrolls_Study_Edition.pdf

Comment: In grad school we learned that the waw and the yod were used to substitute for vowel sounds, and the pointings came later.

Answer (score 2):

The spelling in the Bible is always אֱלֹהִים, never אֱלוֹהִים. The /o/ sound comes from the diacritic on the letter ל; vowels aren't always indicated by letters. In Modern Hebrew, the trend is for vowels to be systematically indicated by letters when possible, so the ordinary spelling is אֱלוֹהִים.

Comment: There are no vowel pointings in ancient Hebrew.  They were added in 900 A.D., (In the Aleppo Codex).

Comment: @elikakohen There were vowels in ancient Hebrew. The vowel pointings are a convention for marking them in writing

Comment: Could you address the other aspect of the question which is the spelling (without any pointing)? If אלהים is the plural of אלוה, then why isn't it אלוהים?

Comment: @RevelationLad I don't see that asked in the question. But it's an interesting question in its own right. Maybe to avoid ambiguity with אֵלֶּה

Comment: In ancient manuscripts before vowel pointings were added "אלוהים" did in fact occur.  This could be confusing to outsiders since that spelling could potentially be pronounced "elwahim" by those who didn't know any better.  The possible confusion between whether the waw was meant as a consonant or as a vowel was one reason pointings were invented.

Comment: @Traildude Not in unvocalized or vocalized Masoretic texts. But in Qumran texts that spelling does appear.

Answer (score 1):

In traditional vocalization, the א is elided when a prefixed clitic is added. Thus, “to God” is לֵאלֹהִים (lelohím) rather than לֶאֱלֹהִים (le'elohím).
Observant Jews, outside of prayer, may prefer to write and say אֱלוֹקִים‎ (elokím), so as not to abuse the name of God.

See https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%94%D7%99%D7%9D

Answer (score -1):

There’s no ‘O’ to be sounded in today’s spelling. Ancients weren’t  any more complicated in writing language than we are.

The Masoretes took it upon themselves to take certain things out (such as the waw) and substitute with dots and such. I suppose they thought it would be less confusing for some to read.

Bear in mind that was done 1000 yrs after the destruction of the Temple.  The main purpose for the 70 was to have uniformity in how words were pronounced in Synagogues everywhere ... based on what “they thought” at the time it should sound like.

Best to use the Septuagint which was translated by scribes under the supervision of Hillel in Jerusalem 200 yrs before the destruction of the Temple. They still spoke Aramaic and had access to scrolls in both Heb & Aramaic.

Comment: Welcome to Bible Hermeneutics SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803).

Comment: @JBosque. Hillel was not yet alive 200 years before the Temple was destroyed. And the LXX was produced in Alexandria, Egypt, not Jerusalem.